# Adding Drop-down Menus to the Navigation Bar

Tags: php, html, css

I am just a beginner to HTML, CSS, PHP, javaScript.
My drop down menus to the navigation bar is not working.
When I keep the mouse over the links in navigation bar, no drop down menu is apeearing.
Need a help from some one.

**CODE**

```
<head>

      #menu {
             width:1060px;
             margin:auto;
             padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
             position:relative;
             }

      #menu ul {
                height:25px;
                font-size:20px;
                font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-weight:bold;
                text-align:center;
                background-color:#8AD9FF;
                border-radius:18px;
                margin-top:10px;
                margin-bottom:5px;
                list-style:none;
               }

       #menu ul li{
                   border-style:solid;
                   border-width:2px;
                   border-bottom:none;
                   border-top:none;
                   border-color:#0000FF;
                   display:inline-block;
                   text-decoration:none;
                   color:#FF0000;
                   padding-bottom:0px;
                   padding-top:0px;
                   margin-right:-8px;
                  }

        #menu ul li a {
                       padding-left:25px;
                       padding-right:25px
                      }

        #menu ul li a:link{
                           color:#3366CC;
                           text-decoration:none;
                          }

        #menu ul li a:visited{
                              color:#3366CC;
                              text-decoration:none;
                             }

        #menu ul li a:hover{
                            background-color:#3399FF;
                            text-decoration:underline;
                           }

        #menu ul ul {
                     display:none;
                     width:125px;
                    }

        #menu ul li a:hover > ul {
                                    margin:0px;
                                    padding:0px;
                                 }

        #menu ul li a:hover > ul li {
                                     float:none;
                                     display:block;
                                    }

        #menu ul li a:hover > ul li a {
                                       color:#3366CC;
                                       min-width:150px;
                                      }

        #menu ul li a:hover > ul li a:hover {
                                               background-color:#3399FF;
                                               text-decoration:underline;
                                             }

        #menu ul li {position:relative;}

        #menu ul li ul {
                          position:absolute;
                          top:30px;
                          left:0px;
                        }

</head>

<body>

      <div id="menu">
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
              <li><a href="#">College</a>
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Faculties & Departments</a></li>
                      <li><a href=#"">Centres</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">College Facts</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Awards</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="">Education</a>
                  <ul>
                       <li><a href="#">Pahrmacy Law Exam Review Course</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Doctor Of Pharm Degree (Pharm. D.)</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Graduate Programs</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Online MS Programs</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Research</a>
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Medicina lChemistry</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Doctor Of Pharm Degree (Pharm. D.)</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Graduate Programs</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Online MS Programs</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Faculty &amp; Staff</a>
                   <ul>
                       <li><a href="#">Faculty Directory</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Staff Dierctory</a></li>
                   </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
         </ul>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
#menu ul li:hover > ul{
display: block;
}
```

Try to comment those line here :

```
 #menu ul li ul {
    position:absolute;
    /*top:30px;*/
    left:0px;
  }
```

and :

```
#menu ul {
    height:25px;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#8AD9FF;
    border-radius:18px;
    /*margin-top:10px;*/
    margin-bottom:5px;
    list-style:none;
    }
```

Comment: again a prob
when I keep the mouse over the links in the navigation bar, the drop doen menu is appearing now. But when I try to go through the drop down menu, it is suddenly disappearing. can u plz help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following code

```
 #menu ul li a:hover > ul {
   float:none;
    display:block;
  }
```

The above code will display the child levels when they hover the anchor element. But in your code it is a sibling element not child element. So use next sibling element syntax like below.

```
 #menu ul li a:hover + ul {
   float:none;
    display:block;
  }
```

But after this you have to do so many things to works your menu better way. This will fix the hover display issue only.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ka4JA/)

Comment: thanx ur code is also working
yeah u are right. drop down menu is messed up totally. can u please help me to make it better

Comment: again a prob
when I keep the mouse over the links in the navigation bar, the drop doen menu is appearing now. But when I try to go through the drop down menu, it is suddenly disappearing. can u plz help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without JS or PHP. You have an extra `a` tag in most of your CSS. You shouldn't show the nested `ul` when someone hovers over the anchor, you should show it when someone hovers over the list  item:

```
#menu ul li ul { 
  display: none; 
}
#menu ul li:hover ul { 
  display: block; 
}
```

Likewise, the above style hides the entire nested `ul` instead of each `li`, which is cumbersome. Show and hide only one thing: the containing element.

I would recommend some more organization to keep things straight.

instead of writing `ul ul{}`, it may help you to write `ul li ul{}`, at least until this code becomes natural to you.

You also have a lot of extra pseudo elements in there. For instance:

```
#menu ul li a:hover > ul li a:hover {
  background-color:#3399FF;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

doesn't need the pseudo element `:hover` on the first `a` tag (which would be on the `li` tag anyway). Since you can only see the second `a` tag on hover, it can have this style all of the time:

```
#menu ul li ul li a:hover {
  background-color:#3399FF;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: again a prob
when I keep the mouse over the links in the navigation bar, the drop doen menu is appearing now. But when I try to go through the drop down menu, it is suddenly disappearing. can u plz help me to solve this issue

Comment: Yes, you need to check your margins to make sure there is no gap between your `li:hover` and the `li` of your dropdown menu. Since the dropdown menu is inside the first `li`, when you scroll over it, you're still technically hovering over the first `li`. When there's a margin that creates a gap, you're scrolling your mouse outside of the first `li` to get to the dropdown menu.

Comment: thanx loadz n loadz for ur guidance & quick response